# Python - Wildcards for integer values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, wildcard

How would I make my code round any value that has a decimal point of x.999999999?

The code so far I have is:

```
y = int(input("Enter a cube number "))
cuberoot = y**(1/3)
if cuberoot.is_integer():
    print("integer")
else:
    if cuberoot == HERE.9999999:
        print("Integer")
    else:
        print("not integer")
```

help
(where it says "HERE" is what do i put there)

Answer (score 2):

Use modulo operator.

```
y = int(input("Enter a cube number "))
cuberoot = y ** (1/3)
fraction = cuberoot % 1
if fraction == 0 or fraction > 0.999999:
    print("integer")
else:
    print("not integer")
```

Comment: This works perfectly, now how do i set a question as answered

Comment: For reference, the smallest number this fails on is 193,100,551, which is not a cube (it's 578^3 - 1).

Answer (score 1):

Using an error-tolerance will give you incorrect results for large numbers. For example, 10<sup>12</sup> - 1 is not a cube, but `(10**12 - 1) ** (1/3)` is `9999.999999996662` which would pass your test.

A safer way to do this would be to round it to an integer, then check whether it has the right cube:

```py
def is_cube(x):
    y = x ** (1/3)
    y = int(round(y))
    if y ** 3 == x:
        print('Integer')
    else:
        print('Not integer')
```

Examples:

```py
>>> is_cube(27)
Integer
>>> is_cube(28)
Not integer
>>> is_cube(10**12)
Integer
>>> is_cube(10**12 - 1)
Not integer
```

However, note that this won't work for *very* large numbers, since `x ** (1/3)` is done using floating-point numbers, so the error might be greater than 0.5, in which case the rounding will give the wrong result. For example, the above code fails for the input `10 ** 45`.